# Convert parcelable Kotlin class with parent class to JSON

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, parcelable

In my Android Kotlin project, I have an abstract class and a child class that inherits the abstract class:

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractExample(
    val test2: String,
    val test3: String) : Parcelable
```

```kotlin
@Parcelize
class Example(
    val test1: String,
    test2: String,
    test3: String) : AbstractExample(test2, test3)
```

Because I want my `Example` class to be parcelable, I use the `@Parcelize` annotation.

The problem is: I get the following error on `test2` and `test3` in the `Example` class:

```
'Parcelable' constructor parameter should be 'val' or 'var'.
```

So to fix that, I tried the following:

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractExample(
    open val test2: String,
    open val test3: String) : Parcelable
```

```kotlin
@Parcelize
class Example(
    val test1: String,
    override val test2: String,
    override val test3: String) : AbstractExample(test2, test3)
```

Now it compiles, but then I get a new problem: if I want to use Gson to convert the `Example` class to JSON (so I can send it to a webservice, for example), then I get the following error:

```
Example declares multiple JSON fields named test2
```

How can I then fix my two classes so I can parcelize my `Example` class, and also be able to convert it into JSON using Gson?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A little research lead me to [this](https://medium.com/@dev.malwinder/gson-parcelize-inheritance-for-a-data-class-6536e9c41fa7), so here is how to fix it:

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractExample(
    @Transient open val test2: String,
    @Transient open val test3: String) : Parcelable
```

```kotlin
@Parcelize
class Example(
    val test1: String,
    override val test2: String,
    override val test3: String) : AbstractExample(test2, test3)
```